# How to link a MainMenu tab with a PrintDialog

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Ok, so here i am asking a rediculous question again but, how would i link a **Main Menu** tab called *Print* with a **PrintDialog**?
Once again, my text book did not provide this solution. Only for using a button to engage the print dialog.
I have tried using the method using the button but there is always an error.
Thanks for taking time to read my query.

Comment: Dude, "there is an error" is lazy, shabby, and not acceptable.  When you try something, show exactly WHAT you tried, and the error you got.    Your text book isn't going to have `99.9999999%` of what you need. You're gonna have to try something, think about it, and when you ask a question here, ask a smart non-lazy question.

Answer (score 1):

Just call the `PrintDialog.Execute` method from the menu item `OnClick` event:

```
procedure TForm1.PrintDialogMenu1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if PrintDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    // Your code to print here
  end;
end;
```

Note that `TPrintDialog` does not do the actual printing for you. Delphi 7 comes with Rave Reports (IIRC - I don't have Delphi 7 here to check). You have to create your report yourself, and actually print it where I've indicated above. You should be able to find a tutorial for Rave Reports by searching Google or Bing for "Rave Reports Delphi".